# send key for right arrow

Tags: .net

what is the syntax for the sendkey for rightarrow  in .net?

Comment: Methinks your google is broken? :)

Comment: Mitch Wheat: Mwell... if you want people to google over to Stack Overflow then answer it yourself. ;P

Comment: That's strange I thought I already had?

Answer (score 1):

{RIGHT}

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Google is your friend.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)

{RIGHT}

Comment: There are people who think pointing someone to Google is rude. Well, I'm not one of them. ;-)

Comment: A link to the actual Google search would be even better http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en-GB&q=what+is+the+syntax+for+the+sendkey+for+rightarrow+in+.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
And this page comes first!

Comment: This site gets indexed by Google pretty fast.